# How can I automatically exit vim via a bash command in a .sh file?

Tags: bash, vim

I am writing a bash script (.sh file) to run a program called "lenstool". Before fully running as I type directly in the terminal, "lenstool" opens a text file in vim. I must quit vim by typing :q and hitting enter. Then the program would do what it is supposed to do.
Now, I want run "lenstool" a few thousand times. How can I automatically exit vim within a bash script file?

Comment: I'm confused about the question. Is `lenstool` a program you wrote? Can you change it?

Comment: No, it is a package that I installed and I would like to learn how to exit programs in the terminal in general.

Comment: Can you change which editor is called by lenstool? Maybe it uses the EDITOR environment variable, so you can switch vim to something more "batch-friendly". Or maybe you can change the way vim gets called and use its [ex mode](http://superuser.com/questions/22455/vim-what-is-the-ex-mode-for-batch-processing-for).

Comment: Another thought, which version of lenstool are you using? A quick search found at least two that seem to fit, [one written in C and Perl](https://projets.lam.fr/projects/lenstool) and [one written in Python](http://www.columbia.edu/~ap3020/LensTools/html/). The latter one has an API. So maybe it would be easier to write your script in Python and use that API, instead of wrangling vim around ;)

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to my mind is doing:

```
id=$(ps -A | grep vim | awk '{print $1}')
```

to get pid(s) of the running vim program(s) and then kill it with:

```
kill $id
```

of course you need to save your work first and then do this. I'm not sure how your program saves what is has done!